# equivalence of measures on separable spaces

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to check if my conclusion is right.

Let $(X, \|\cdot \|_1)$ be a separable normed space endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra $B$ generated by the norm $\|\cdot \|_{1}$. Therefore, since the measurable space $(X, B)$ is separable, then $\sigma$-algebra $B$ is equal to the one generated by the open balls in $(X, \|\cdot \|_1)$. Therefore, two measures are equal if and only if they agree on the finite intersections of open balls, since the finite intersections of the balls in $(X, \|\cdot \|_1)$ constitute a $\pi$-system.

Next, consider the norm $\|\cdot \|_2$ on $X$, which is equivalent to $\|\cdot \|_1$. Since $||\cdot ||_2$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot \|_1$, then they define the same topologies and, therefore, the same $\sigma$-algebras. Then I conclude the following:

in order to prove that two measures on $(X, B)$ are equivalent, one has to show that they agree on the the finite intersections of open balls, balls in ANY norm equivalent to $\|\cdot \|_1$.

Comment: Seems good. Only remark: When you say "the sigma algebra generated by $\|\cdot\|$", what you really mean is "the sigma algebra generated by the topology generated by $\|\cdot\|$", right? Also, at least in finite dimensions, you do not need to take the finite intersections, the balls alone will do.

Comment: In some metric spaces, balls alone do not suffice.  I don't know whether balls suffice in separable normed spaces.

Comment: dear @PhoemueX, yes, this is what I mean. Thank you!
dear GEdgar, yes, of course, ball alone is not enough.